# Jena Fuseki Server command not found

Tags: sparql, semantics, jena, fuseki

I am new to Jena Fuseki server. According to the link http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/index.html, after I downloaded and unzipped it on my Fedora machine,I tried to start the server using command line.

Under the Fuseki directory, the command should be like this: **fuseki-server --update --mem /ds**, yet it gave the error: **fuseki-server command not found**.

Is there anyone who knows what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: if you found a solution, and it looks like you have, you should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.  For the moment, I've copied your solution and posted it as (a community wiki) answer, and removed it from the question.

Answer (score 2):

> *This was posted as [an edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11141889/2), but is actually an answer.*

Some colleague helped me figure this out. It's a Linux problem, not a Fuseki problem. The error means the system doesn't know where to find **fuseki-server**, so you have to put it on the PATH, or specify the location where the command is, e.g.:

```
/opt/jena-fuseki-0.2.2/fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Maybe you can read through the sequence below and see what you did differently:

```
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ cd /tmp
[/tmp] 
ian@ian-desktop $ mkdir fuseki-test
[/tmp] 
ian@ian-desktop $ cd fuseki-test
[/tmp/fuseki-test] 
ian@ian-desktop $ wget http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/jena-fuseki-0.2.2-distribution.tar.gz
--2012-06-21 17:04:46--  http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/jena-fuseki-0.2.2-distribution.tar.gz
Resolving www.apache.org (www.apache.org)... 192.87.106.229, 140.211.11.131, 2001:610:1:80bc:192:87:106:229
Connecting to www.apache.org (www.apache.org)|192.87.106.229|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9183962 (8.8M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `jena-fuseki-0.2.2-distribution.tar.gz'

100%[==========================================================>] 9,183,962    783K/s   in 11s     

2012-06-21 17:04:58 (780 KB/s) - `jena-fuseki-0.2.2-distribution.tar.gz' saved [9183962/9183962]

[/tmp/fuseki-test] 
ian@ian-desktop $ tar -xvzf jena-fuseki-0.2.2-distribution.tar.gz
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/fuseki-server.jar
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/LICENSE
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/NOTICE
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/ReleaseNotes.txt
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/DEPENDENCIES
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/s-update
... more ....
jena-fuseki-0.2.2/fuseki-server
[/tmp/fuseki-test] 
ian@ian-desktop $ cd jena-fuseki-0.2.2/
[/tmp/fuseki-test/jena-fuseki-0.2.2] 
ian@ian-desktop $ ./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
17:05:55 INFO  Server               :: Dataset: in-memory
17:05:55 INFO  Server               :: Dataset path = /ds
17:05:55 INFO  Server               :: Fuseki 0.2.2 2012-06-13T14:59:26+0100
17:05:55 INFO  Server               :: Jetty 7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
17:05:55 INFO  Server               :: Started 2012/06/21 17:05:55 BST on port 3030
^C[/tmp/fuseki-test/jena-fuseki-0.2.2] 
ian@ian-desktop $
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem. What I did then was to install the latest version of the java SDK or the version suggested by Jena Fuseki. In my case, I installed Java SDK version 11, and the problem was solved.