# What perquisites, if any, are there for installing Jena Fuseki?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but I think this question and its answers could be relevant to a beginner in Jena Fuseki using any operating system (if adapted slightly).

I am trying to install Jena Fuseki, however, the instructions in all the tutorials I have found and on the website are unclear to me. I downloaded this file jena-fuseki-1.1.0-distribution.tar.gz and unzipped it into my home directory.

I then ran the following commands:

```
cd jena-fuseki-1.1.0
mkdir dataDir
chmod +x fuseki-server s-*
fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataSet
```

However this was the output in my terminal after the last command:

```
fuseki-server: command not found
```

I suspect there is something I haven't installed, but require to get this working. i.e.
Do I need Java on my machine? 
Do I need Apache?
Do I need Apache Jena?

Or perhaps it is something entirely different that I am missing. 
Keep in mind I am a beginner, so skipping over the obvious will not help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jena Fuseki Server command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141889/jena-fuseki-server-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have JAVA installed to successfully run Fuseki, but by the looks of your error you have it installed already, otherwise you would be getting an error message 'java: not found' (or similar).

Except for java there shouldn't be any other dependencies. [I had a similar problem to you which I just solved](https://web.archive.org/web/20160511194222/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/29847/how-do-i-install-jena-fuseki-on-ubuntu-1404#29855) and apparently it is a Linux problem and not a Fuseki error. This is what I did to get it working:

1. Download the 'apache-jena-2.12.0.tar.gz' and extract it to your (root)/opt folder (which seem to be the directory which is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not a part of the default installation).
2. The folder I extracted into /opt was called jena-fuseki-1.1.0, if you have a different name you have to change jena-fuseki-1.1.0 in the next two commands to the folder name you have. Run this command: `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jena-fuseki-1.1.0`
3. Then run: `export FUSEKI_HOME=/opt/jena-fuseki-1.1.0`
4. If you want a persistent data store you should create a new folder in the 'jena-fuseki-1.1.0' folder in which to store the data. You do this by running `mkdir dataDir` from within the 'jena-fuseki-1.1.0' folder;  (if you) call it 'dataDir' (you should) then run: `fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataset`. You can change the name of 'dataDir' if you like and you can also pick a different name for /myDataset if you like which is the name you use when making calls to your database.

You don't need to download Jena seperately to use Fuseki.
That is all; you can now browse to 'localhost:3030' and start SPARQLing away :)

```
./fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataSet
```

Comment: What should be the data set folder owner? I get the following error following your guide when I reach the run phase:
FusekiConfigException: FUSEKI_BASE is not writable: /opt/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.1/data-store/run

Answer (score 1):

The current dir `.` is usually not in the path for security reasons. Try:

```
./fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataSet
```

Also see [Jena Fuseki Server command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141889/jena-fuseki-server-command-not-found).

Comment: The question that you linked to already seems to contain an answer to this question. (The answer was originally posted as an edit to the question, but I've added a community wiki answer, so it's a bit clearer now.) It might have been more appropriate to simply flag as a duplicate.